# Weird syntax error after creating a new project in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I created a new project: `laravel new myprojectname` and I am getting a blank page. First, I thought is about the permission so I gave the 777 to the storage folder, but I still had the blank page. Then I checked the logs and I saw this:

```
    production.ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting 
variable (T_VARIABLE) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug
\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Parse error: syntax error, 
unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) at /opt/lampp/htdocs
/myprojectname/vendor/symfony/routing/Route.php:53)  .....
```

My php version is: `7.1.14` . Does anyone know why I get this ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you're running on `PHP 7.1.14`? Did you confirm with `phpinfo();`?

Comment: hmmm , I am using opt/lampp server on ubuntu, and the phpinfo shows me this version: `PHP Version 7.0.9`, but still

Comment: What is your laravel version?

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.6.3

Comment: OK, but in that case I have to upgrade my php version from lampp to php7.1 or php7.2, right ? Do you know how ? :P

Comment: @Chester You just need to use the `php 7.1` on your webserver instead of `7.0.9`.

Comment: I currently have 7.0.9 and I would like to upgrade it to 7.1 or 7.2 . How can I do that ? I don't want to reinstall my lampp in Ubuntu, cuz I will lost the database and etc. and doing backups it takes too long. So I am looking for a solution to upgrade it to 7.1 and without any success :(

Comment: Just enable the `php7.1` module with `a2enmod php7.1` instead of the `7.0`

Comment: @ChinLeung can you be a little bit more specific ? `a2enmod` ? I have no idea what is that :(

Comment: @ChinLeung that is for the apache service. I am using Xampp on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` at line `53` is the new `nullable types` introduced in [PHP 7.1](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php), and you are running `PHP 7.0.9`, hence the reason why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel just upgraded to 5.6 and it requires PHP 7.13.

Also, after you upgrade your PHP, make sure you upgrade PHPUnit ~7.0, fideloper/proxy ~4.0, and Symfony ~4.0.

Follow this link [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade) for full upgrade details.